# Is Google Place API linked to an email account?

Tags: wordpress, google-places-api

I have a former person that setup my Wordpress website and there is an API entered for Google Place. Is this Google Place API attached to a Google account in which the API could potentially be revoked by this person in the future? Or is the API directly issued by Google? I just want to ensure continuity on my Wordpress without a feature breaking in the future.

Comment: Discussed here: https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/ I bet. Depends on your plan.

Answer (score 0):

The API is connected to the former person's Google account. I am unsure if the person can revoke the API key.

To be on the safe side, make your own [API KEY](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key)